# Magento2.4.4-p2 admin open category tree get error "A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing."

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4

Magento version is 2.4.4-p2. PHP version is 8.1.

Go to Admin ==> Marketing ==> Promotions ==> Cart Price Rules. Click "Add New Rule" to create new rule.
In this page, go to "Conditions" tab, to add category as condition. click button to open category tree to select category. got the error "A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We compared to the Magento 2.4.1(this version do not have this issue). Found their jquery version are difference. And the higher JQuery(Magneto 2.4.4-p2, version is 3.6) will check the url from `<script id="ie-deferred-loader" defer="defer" src="//:"></script>` and think it is invalid.

So we find the file vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/category/checkboxes/tree.phtml and remove the code `<script id="ie-deferred-loader" defer="defer" src="//:"></script>`. It fix the error. And also checked in IE, it do not have other issues.